# CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition mvc 3.0.0.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, publish

All my Model objects are broken now. I had to do the MVC 3.0.0.1 update, and now I can't get any pages to load.

The site works fine locally. But I can't figure out what the deal is on the server. I've checked, and the bin folders have identical .dlls.

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<HIVE.Controllers.HomeViewModel>" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div id="content">

       <div class="marquee">
            <div class="pointer">
                <%
                    foreach (var i in Model.CurrentImportantEvents)
```

and then in the controller...

```
namespace HIVE.Controllers
{
    public class HomeViewModel
    {
        public IQueryable<v_ImportantEvent> CurrentImportantEvents { get; private set; }

        public HomeViewModel()
        {
            this.CurrentImportantEvents = new COMRepository().GetVImportantEvents(DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
```

Edit: I dunno if this matters but I notice that the server copy requires a System.Web.Mvc.dll in the bin folder, but the local copy doesn't. I can delete it and it doesn't seem to care. If I delete the server version there's a cannot find MVC 3.0.0.1 error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is dumb but I'll put it here in hopes that it benefits someone else.

I had to manually change all the System.Web.Mvc version numbers referenced in all the Web.Config files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that you don't have MVC3 security update installed on your server, but your dev machine has. The mvc security update put mvc.dll 3.0.0.1 in the GAC and a publisher policy onto the machine which binding redirects mvc 3.0.0.0 to 3.0.0.1. That's why you don't have to change anything on your dev box and it works fine.